# ListView not Showing any items

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to display array items in ListView using ArrayAdapter. it's not showing any items in ListView and not showing any error's below is my java class and xml.

```
package church.llagc.com;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class listView extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    String[] alphabitlist = {"A","Aa","I","EE","U","Uu","E","EI","O","Oo","Ka","Ga","Cha","Ja","Tha","Da","Na","Pa","Ba",
            "Bha","Ma","Ya","Ra","La","Va","Ssa","Sha","Sa","Ha"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,alphabitlist);
        ListView alpabits = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alphabitorder);
        alpabits.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

containt_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="church.llagc.com.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

   <include layout="@layout/activity_list_view"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my activity_list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="church.llagc.com.listView">

    <ListView
        android:background="@drawable/alphabit_bg"
        android:id="@+id/alphabitorder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/itemcontent"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="8"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Please comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: Post this layout as well `simple_list_item_1`.

Comment: Do you want a list of list?

Comment: It's not good to use `wrap_content` for your listview heights; use `match_parent` or a fixed height instead. Depending on the platform version, that might fix things.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: yes, I want a list of list. my first list show list. when I click on it that will show a related list

Comment: I tried your code, it seems to be working fine. I see a listView on the left with all the strings

Comment: I tried in another activity its working fine but it's not working on this layout. problem is in containt_main.xml

Comment: Your question includes this code `setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view)`, so `containt_main.xml` doesn't seem to be referenced anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   <ListView
    android:background="@drawable/alphabit_bg"
    android:id="@+id/alphabitorder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:scrollbars="none"/>

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/itemcontent"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="8"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i changed to match_parent it's showing the background color but not showing text

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and create you own layout file. This `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` layout file has a simple `text view` but the text color is something related to white that's why you cant see it. Now you have to create a new layout file which contain only `text view` and set `text color` and pass it to your adapter

Comment: If this winds up being the cause, another option would be to continue to use the same layout resource but change your activity's theme so that `android:textColorPrimary` is some visible text color.

Comment: my background color is gray so it's not the text color

Comment: add screenshots, what you seeing